# MySQL mysterious error

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, phpmyadmin, cursor

PHPMyAdmin keeps telling me, that I got an error at line 41 (third last line) . I can't seem to locate it, any help/advice will be appreciated. I've double-checked the IF-THEN syntax, and cursors.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE `done` BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
DECLARE `a` TEXT;
DECLARE `cur` CURSOR FOR SELECT `mana_cost` FROM `cards`;   
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done`=TRUE;



OPEN `cur`;

read_loop : LOOP

    FETCH `cur` INTO `a`;
    IF `done`
    THEN LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    IF `a` LIKE '%{B}%'
    THEN            
        UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'BLACK '
        WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
    ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{G}%'
    THEN            
        UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'GREEN '
        WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
    ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{U}%'
    THEN            
        UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'BLUE '
        WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
    ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{W}%'
    THEN            
        UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'WHITE '
        WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
    ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{R}%'
    THEN            
        UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'RED '
        WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    

    END IF;

END LOOP;  //line 41
CLOSE `cur`;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very common, it's because MySQL stop to create the procedure when it sees a ";"

you need to use a DELIMITER to wrap your procedure ;)

**DELIMITER $**
BEGIN
DECLARE `done` BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
DECLARE `a` TEXT;
DECLARE `cur` CURSOR FOR SELECT `mana_cost` FROM `cards`;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done`=TRUE;

OPEN `cur`;

read_loop : LOOP

```
FETCH `cur` INTO `a`;
IF `done`
THEN LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

IF `a` LIKE '%{B}%'
THEN            
    UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'BLACK '
    WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{G}%'
THEN            
    UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'GREEN '
    WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{U}%'
THEN            
    UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'BLUE '
    WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{W}%'
THEN            
    UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'WHITE '
    WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    
ELSE IF `a` LIKE '%{R}%'
THEN            
    UPDATE `cards` SET `color` = 'RED '
    WHERE `mana_cost` = `a`;    

END IF;
```

END LOOP;  //line 41
CLOSE `cur`;
END **$**
**DELIMITER ;**

You should try something like that and look the documentation about DELIMITER and MySQL jokes :P

Comment: But I do it with phpmyadmin, and I don't need a delimiter there (at least I didn't need it with any other procedure)

Comment: It started to crash when I added else-if

Answer (score 0):

```
LEAVE read_loop ;
END LOOP read_loop ;
```

Add the loop name and a LEAVE statement.